# How to change login, password, host of a Postgres database dynamically? Multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, elixir, erlang-supervisor

I have multipe Postgres repositories in my app. I use Ecto. All works.

Now I want to be able to change their details, such as login, password, host, dynamically. That is, I’d change login/password/hostname of a database via an html page, restart the connection with a database and it should continue working.

How can I do that?

I don’t want to use any third-party library.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to start the respective `GenServer` to manage the connection. Assuming you have a repo config in `repo_config` variable, you might:

```rb
{:ok, pid} <- MyApp.Repo.start_link(repo_config)
```

This server should be started supervised, otherwise, it might crash and the connection will be lost forever. For supervising dynamically started `GenServer`s we use [`DynamicSupervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DynamicSupervisor.html?).

---

Also, you might use *the same repo* to manage different connections. In such a case, [`Ecto.Repo.put_dynamic_repo/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:put_dynamic_repo/1) and [`Ecto.Repo.get_dynamic_repo/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:get_dynamic_repo/0) are your friends.

```rb
current_pid = MyApp.Repo.get_dynamic_repo()
MyApp.Repo.put_dynamic_repo(repo_pid)
# deal with repo 
MyApp.Repo.put_dynamic_repo(current_pid)
```

In a vast majority of cases, the first approach (multiple repos) is preferred.

Comment: Which is what I should use? My requirements are: 1) start the repositories, dynamically 2) restart each one, on demand, dynamically, when the config is changed 3) I might need only one or two repositories/modules overall. Even if I have 100 different Postgresql endpoints. That is, only 1 will be the main repo -- the admin dashboard, and the other one will be the current client repo.

Comment: I have answered your question about how to achieve what you wanted. “What should I use” kind of question implies the opinionated answer, and SO rules explicitly deny giving opinionated answers. Use whatever you think is more suitable for your needs. Try both, and pick one that performs more smoothly.

Comment: What should I use Aleksei?